# computing mse from log transformed variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-transformation

If one is dealing with a general regression formula as such:

$\hat{Y} = f(\hat{X})$,

where $\hat{Y}$ is the log transformation of the output variable in the training data set, how does one compute the MSE? Does one compute MSE using the original dataset by exponentiating the predictions on the test set?

Comment: Doing that would be meaningless if you are fitting the model using a least-squares technique, because the solution based on logarithms is not the least-squares solution based on the original data.  How you proceed must depend on what you intend to do with this MSE and how you will interpret it.  Could you supply more information about those?

Comment: Hi. I'm fitting the model using boosted regression trees. I was not getting good results initially, because there are many, many outliers in my data. Log-transforming the output variable was something I tried, I was wondering about the validity of it.